# A new Instances of Singleton Class in PHP for each HTTP request

Tags: php, web-applications, singleton

I have the following Singleton Class in PHP.

```
class CounterBalance{
    private static $instance;

    private $counterBalance;

    private function __construct(){ 
        $this->counterBalance = mt_rand(1, 4);      
    }

    // Getter method for creating/returning the single instance of this class
    public final static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new CounterBalance();
            echo "CounterBalance constructed <br/>";
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function getCounterBalanceValue() {
        return $this->counterBalance;
    }

}
```

But in the class when I do something like

```
CounterBalance::getInstance()->getCounterBalanceValue();
```

on the same php page, it works properly. But it not working properly across pages. I get more than one instance of CounterBalance, when I do the same function call in the subsequent php page.

Can anyone one please explain why this happens.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Welcome to the stateless world of HTTP.

A singleton can only persist for the single page load (or any other PHP data structure, for that matter). When the php process dies, the singleton dies with it. The next time a page is loaded the singleton is created all over again. The singleton is only alive in the context of that single process. If you tried to create ten instances of it during a single script execution you would maintain the single instance.

If you need data persistence across pages you'll have to implement an agent of state. For example, the `$_SESSION` or `$_GET` superglobals or store data in a database (for example) and re-retrieve it on subsequent page loads.